# AJAX pagination with back button Drupal view

Tags: views, ajax

I have one view of a multimedia page wherein I use AJAX for pagination. The view shows the result of a multimedia image. When I click on the image it goes to the inner content page. In the inner content page there is a back button. When I click the button, it goes back to the previous page from where I came.

When I click on the back button it always forwards me to the multimedia page. But I want it to forward me to pagination page 2 if I came from page 2.

Comment: What about passing the page number in the http request (using GET method for example)

Comment: This sounds like a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module [views_ajax_history](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_ajax_history) which uses https://github.com/browserstate/history.js to maintain the current state of page and push them into browse history with HTML5 history api. This library support fallback if history api is not supported by older browser.